# How can I read geospatial data from MySQL into R?

Tags: mysql, r, gis, geospatial, dplyr

I am reading from a MySQL database into R.  I can read the table of interest using dplyr without a problem - except for the geometry column which contains MULTILINE(...).  Is there a way to read polylines into R directly from MySQL?

When I read the table containing the geometry column, it gives a warning "unrecognized MySQL field type 255 in column 5 imported as character", and for each record for which the geometry column is not NA, it gives an additional warning such as "internal error: row 51 field 5 truncated"

Answer (score 1):

If your `MySQL` column is a a spatial SQL object you may consider using the `ogr2ogr` which is a popular command line utility to handle spatial data formats. For example you could do:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:gis,user=root,password=password C:\file.shp -nln pianco_post -a_srs EPSG:29194 -update -overwrite -lco engine=MYISAM
```

As discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131681/exporting-spatial-object-in-mysql-to-shapefile-with-spatial-reference).

If you wish to do everything in R you can use the [R wrapper](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/functions/ogr2ogr) for the `ogr2ogr`. Then you would just read your shapefiles into R, this is discussed at lengths across SO, and use along any other objects you may have.